# Angular binding array and boolean/string datatypes

Tags: angularjs, typescript, binding, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I am a beginner in `angular` and `typescript`.

my service inside a module in typescript looks like below

```
module MyModule {
class HelloService {

    public data:string[] = ["1","2","3"];
    public booleanvalue:boolean = false;
    public stringvalue:string = "hai";

    public test() {
        this.data.push("hai");
        this.booleanvalue = true;
        this.stringvalue = "Hai welcome";
    }

    }

    angular.module('MyModule', []).service('hexafy', function () {
        return new HelloService();
    });
}
```

I compile the above and add the obtained JavaScript reference in a HTML file with below div element

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <br/>
        <button ng-click="buttonClick()">Click Me! </button> <br>
    <br/>
    <label>{{value}}</label><br>
</div>
```

myCtrl after `injecting` the `service` hexafy looks as below

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['MyModule']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope' , 'hexafy'  , MyController]);

function MyController($scope, hexafy)
{
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.thirdpartyfactory = hexafy;
    vm.value = vm.thirdpartyfactory.stringvalue;// the problem is in this line
    vm.buttonClick = function(){
    vm.thirdpartyfactory.test();
}
```

here is my question.
If I bind "data" to vm.value, it changes on button click, but if I bind `booleanvalue` or `stringvalue` to vm.value, it is not updating.

What would be the reason for this

Answer (score 1):

I think its because when you do:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var copy = array ;
copy.push(4);
// array : [1,2,3,4]
```

its because you bind `s` by **reference** to `bla`;

but when you do

```
var number = 2;
var other = number;
other += 1;
// number : 2
// other : 3
```

its because you bind `other` by **value** to `number`;

to fix this issue you need to do:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <br/>
    <button ng-click="buttonClick()">Click Me! </button> <br>
  <br/>
  <label>{{thirdpartyfactory.stringvalue}}</label><br>
</div>
```